# Disable feature in master (git)

Tags: git, merge, feature-branch

We are developing a feature in `feature/x`. We need to merge this feature into `master` every now and then and also merge `master` back to `feature/x` to stay in sync. The `feature/x` branch also exists as a remote branch, so rebasing is not a very good option here.

We want to disable/hide the actual feature in `master` until some point in future. In fact, I'd like to be able to create a commit K in `master` such that it disables the feature being developed by hiding it in the UI but preserves the underlying mechanisms.

I'd also want this to work so that when I merge from `master` to `feature/x`, I'll get all commits except K. Also, when I merge from `feature/x` to `master`, the commit K should still apply in `master`, keeping the feature hidden.

I've tried

```
git co master
git commit -am "disable feature x for now"
    => created commit 12345678
git co feature/x
git merge -s ours 12345678
```

This works except the feature gets re-enabled in `master` when I do

```
git co master
git merge feature/x
```

So it seems that merging with `-s ours` from `master` to `feature/x` doesn't result to merge working both ways. So each time I merge from `feature/x` to `master` I'll have to disable the feature again and then this disabling commit will flow back to `feature/x` and so on. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what you are really trying to do *is* a rebase. You could spin fresh branches for each rebase you do, but depending on how frequently you do this it may be impractical.

It's an extra step, but you could set up a (non remoted) branch `feature/disable_x` that contains just the patch to disable `x`. Then when you merge `feature/x` in, rebase and merge `disable_x` as well.

Comment: This does help even though it doesn't do exactly what I'd like to do, i.e. merge both ways without having to do an extra disabling step more than one ever.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using feature flags (or [feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html)).

This allows code to be merged on master but only being available after some flag is toggled (the feature is enabled).

The advantages are numerous:

- easier code management (the code is live)
- easy fallback if something goes wrong: just switch the flag again
- easy gradual go-live: only enable a feature for a few users

Disadvantage: you will have to add some code to manage these flags. But depending on your language/coding platform, libraries will already be available supporting this.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the solution we ended up using. It is indeed more flexible than a version-control based approach.